# using sqlcommand with multiple ids

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, sqlcommand, sqlparameter

So this works great:

```
select name from users where id = @id
```

However, that only selects 1 guy. Say I have 3 IDs instead, normally the SQL would look something like this (without using parameters)

```
select name from users where id in (4,6,9)
```

However, it doesn't seem to work when I write

```
select name from users where id in (@IDs)
```

and insert a list into @IDs, like this

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDs", userIDs);
```

Is there any way to do what I'm trying to? It's important to note that the sql I'm calling is (and has to be) a stored procedure.

Comment: Do you have control over the stored proc?

Comment: It's not made yet, so yes I do.

Comment: You can use a table value parameter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Then what @Hejner said.  You can see an example in an answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-an-sql-in-clause

Comment: Create a temporary table, insert the IDs and join it to the table with the IDs.  With large amounts of IDs you will hit limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this. The first is by passing a string to a stored procedure and then adding it to a dynamic query:

```
-- @IDs  = '4,6,9'
DECLARE @MyQuery nvarchar(max) 
SET @MyQuery = N'SELECT name FROM users WHERE id IN (' + @IDs + ')'
EXEC(@MyQuery)
```

On the other hand, if you are using SQL Server 2008 or later, you can use a table-valued parameter (this is my preference).

First, create a user-defined table type:

```
CREATE TYPE IDList AS TABLE (
  id int
)
```

THEN, use the user defined type as the type for your parameter:

```
DECLARE @IDs IDList 
INSERT INTO @IDs (ID) VALUES (4),(6),(9)
SELECT name FROM users u INNER JOIN @IDs i WHERE u.id = i.id
```

If you are using .NET to consume a stored procedure, you can find sample code for user-defined SQL types on MSDN.

Comment: if you are passing '4,6,9' wouldn't that not work since it needs to look like IN ('4','6','9')

Comment: Tsukasa - If the data type of "ID" is string, then you would want ('4', '6', '9'); but if you look at his original question, it's pretty clear the data type is int or some other numeric type, so no.

Comment: It seems like the execute query is the way to go then, sadly my boss haven't updated our sql server. It just has so many downsides that a "normal" query doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dynamic SQL query inside your stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(500)

SET @SQLQuery = 'select name from users where id in ( ' + @userIDs + ')'

EXECUTE(@SQLQuery)
```

You'll have to be careful and sanitize the contents of @userIDs though to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

On our side we are using iBatis.Net to manage this. Execute query sounds quite ugly but it still does the trick.

We were mostly using string split in SQL. See [question][How do I split a string so I can access item x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/split-string-in-sql)